# In LLVM, how to insert/declare a function with variable number of arguments?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I am trying to extract called functions to another module. I am successful if the function has a defined number of arguments.

```
    // Create the arguments vector from the my argument list
    SmallVector<Type *, sizeof(MyArgs)> ArgTys;
    for (Value *V : MyArgs)
      ArgTys.push_back(V->getType());

    // Just get a void return type
    Type *RetTy = Type::getVoidTy(TempContext);


    // Create a new function with MyArgs as arguments
    Constant *C = TempM->getOrInsertFunction(
        "TempF", FunctionType::get(RetTy, ArgTys, false));
```

But if the function has a variable number of arguments, `getOrInsertFunction` only adds the arguments that I was able to capture with `MyArgs` in `ArgTys`.

---

How do I verify if source function has a variable number of arguments?

How do I use getOrInserFunction to declare a function with variable number of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1FunctionType.html):

1. You can declare a variable argument function by

   `FunctionType::get(RetTy, ArgTys, true);`

(So, in your case, change that `false` argument for the "TempF" function.)

2. You can query if a function is using a variable argument list with the method

   `bool isVarArg() const`

Comment: I really did not see it. Totally overlooked `FunctionType::get` and its third argument. Thank you